# How do I use the AWS CLI to do a lambda serverless deployment for a dotnet 5 project

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, dotnet-cli

Good morning.
I'm trying to use the CLI to do an automated deployments to AWS lambda of my C# lambda project.
With dotnet 3.1 I would do the following.

```
dotnet lambda deploy-serverless --configuration debug --stack-name custom-webhook-dev --s3-bucket custom-deployment-dev --template serverless.dev.template --region us-east-1 --s3-prefix custom-salesforce-integration-
```

This will take care of my deployment to my dev environment, while my production deployment would be similar but replacing dev with prod and debug for release.

But with 5.0 I get the following issue :

```
Amazon Lambda Tools for .NET Core applications (3.2.3)
Project Home: https://github.com/aws/aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli, https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet

Processing CloudFormation resource AspNetCoreFunction
Initiate packaging of . for resource AspNetCoreFunction
Unknown error executing command: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2.FindEntry(TKey key) at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
at Amazon.Lambda.Tools.LambdaUtilities.DetermineTargetFrameworkFromLambdaRuntime(String lambdaRuntime, String projectLocation) in C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src109826539\src\src\Amazon.Lambda.Tools\LambdaUtilities.cs:line 38
at Amazon.Lambda.Tools.TemplateProcessor.TemplateProcessorManager.PackageDotnetProjectAsync(IUpdateResourceField field, String location) in C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src109826539\src\src\Amazon.Lambda.Tools\TemplateProcessor\TemplateProcessorManager.cs:line 223
at Amazon.Lambda.Tools.TemplateProcessor.TemplateProcessorManager.ProcessUpdatableResourceAsync(String templateDirectory, IUpdateResourceField field) in C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src109826539\src\src\Amazon.Lambda.Tools\TemplateProcessor\TemplateProcessorManager.cs:line 167
at Amazon.Lambda.Tools.TemplateProcessor.TemplateProcessorManager.TransformTemplateAsync(String templateDirectory, String templateBody) in C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src109826539\src\src\Amazon.Lambda.Tools\TemplateProcessor\TemplateProcessorManager.cs:line 95
at Amazon.Lambda.Tools.Commands.DeployServerlessCommand.PerformActionAsync() in C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src109826539\src\src\Amazon.Lambda.Tools\Commands\DeployServerlessCommand.cs:line 167
at Amazon.Common.DotNetCli.Tools.Commands.BaseCommand1.ExecuteAsync() in C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src109826539\src\src\Amazon.Common.DotNetCli.Tools\Commands\BaseCommand.cs:line 44
```

It seems to be missing the key for DetermineTargetFrameworkFromLambdaRuntime

What value should this be? What I'm trying to do is just automate the deployment to lambda of my project, Ideally I would like one file to deploy to dev, and 1 file to deploy to production.

One thing that it is missing is the "Runtime" setting that was in 3.1.
Am I supposed to add this on this file or or the command line? And if yes, what value should it be?

The value on a 3.1 template was "Runtime": "dotnetcore3.1",
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure, that AWS lambda supports .NET 5 already?

Answer (score 2):

AWS Lambda doesn't support `.NET 5` yet. Supported versions are :

1. .NET Core 3.1
2. .NET Core 2.1

[Lambda runtimes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html)

`.NET 5` is supported via `container images`

[.NET 5 AWS Lambda Support with Container Images](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/net-5-aws-lambda-support-with-container-images/)

Comment: The project deployed is a container image with dotnet5 that works perfectly if deployed using the wizard. 
The question was how to deploy via CLI.

Comment: @AlejandroGonzalez you can create/update functions via CLI as well take a look here  [Makefile](https://github.com/toddlers/aws-step-function-callback/blob/main/Makefile#L55)